# Error: no attribute '_state'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class User(models.Model):

    user_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_age = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __init__(self, user_id, user_name, user_age):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.user_age = user_age
```

And then I try to create an instance of this model:

```
new_user = User(0, 'Andrew', 25)
new_user.save()
```

But this gives me the error:

```
'User' object has no attribute '_state'
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You should probably make use of Django's `auth` framework, which has a `User` model and several abstract base classes that you can use. This implements a whole lot of features, among others a cryptographically secure method for saving passwords and default login/logout/password reset views etc. [Take a look in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

Answer (score 5):

The code is missing call to super class' `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, user_id, user_name, user_age):
    super(User, self).__init__() # <----
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.user_name = user_name
    self.user_age = user_age
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not really be defining the `__init__` method at all. falsetru shows that you need to call the super class method, but all the functionality you've put in your own version is already provided by that.

Comment: Thanks. But suppose that I want to have some default values for the fields, how can I do that without defining init? Also, if I just use the default init, then I have to explicitly pass the variables with their names, e.g. new_user = User(user_id = 0, user_name = 'Andrew', user_age = 15), whereas I would like to be able to just send these values like this: new_user = User(0, 'Andrew', 15).

Comment: You've already defined the default values in the field declarations themselves.